# strcat expects a restrict * char?

Tags: c, warnings, strcat

I am trying to concat two const char * strings.

When i have a statement like `strcat(a,b)` I get the warning `expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’`

is there a way to call strcat that will not produce the warning?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`strcat()` modifies the first operand. Therefore it cannot be `const`. But you passed it a `const char*`.

So you can't use `strcat()` on two `const *char` strings.

Comment: great thanks! It led to some ugly statements, but works just fine, instead of saying `char * c = strcat(a,b); `  I can use `char * c = strcat(strcat(c,a),b);` provided I've malloc'd c already.

Comment: @user974703: You'd better be sure that you `malloc` *and* set to zero the memory pointed to by `c`, because `malloc` doesn't do that for you. Or, use `strcat(strcpy(c, a), b);`. Or, since `strcat` isn't very efficient, `sprintf(c, "%s%s", a, b);`